# Work with hidden files with windows command line and external tools

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, hibernate

Suppose that hiberfil.sys is located in c:\ and that it is an hidden file

Using commands like `del /H hiberfil.sys` or `xcopy /H hiberfil.sys` will work as both commands are Windows built-in commands and support the /H parameter which seem to make it possible to work with hidden files

But what if I use an external tool like TrID (an utility designed to identify file types from their binary signatures)

```
C:\>trid.exe /H c:\hiberfil.sys

TrID/32 - File Identifier v2.24 

* Error: found no file(s) to analyze!
```

The file can't be found. It won't work at all, how can I solve that problem ?

Comment: why on earth do you delete hiberfil.sys that way? If you want to turn off hibernation then run `powercfg /h off`. And why do you check signature of hiberfil.sys? For what purpose? Does `trid.exe` supports the `/H` flag?

Comment: Command parameters are unique to the command so `/H` likely means nothing to TriD.  If triD isn't designed to work with hidden files, there may be little you can do besides un-hide the file.  But ask yourself why that might be a bad idea - esp. with a system file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense for trid.exe to work on hidden files.  Typically, the files you want to identify are files you are trying to recover and are not hidden.

With that being said, I think this is a limitation of trid.exe.  You can't force it to look at hidden files.  The easiest solution I can give is to use "attrib.exe -h" to unhide the files you want to analyze.  If unhiding is a concern, copy them to a place where you are not concerned about unhiding them.

Comment: no you can't change the hidden attribute of `hiberfil.sys` which is a system file and also managed by the power options. It'll report `Not resetting system file - C:\hiberfil.sys` immediately when you run `attrib -h hiberfil.sys`. To turn off hibernation you **must use `powercfg /H off`**. You must not do anything with the \*.sys files in the root folder. And no one would copy or check the format of hiberfil.sys, that's silly & pointless

Comment: @phuclv, I'm sure there is a nicer way to say that.  The OP may not realize that these are special purpose files.  Even still, I think the question is about how to deal with hidden files.  That is what I answered.  It is not up to you to moderate my answer.  You could have posted your own answer if you have one.